# Redirect Wordpress post url after changing categories

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to add a parent category to my existing posts categories in Wordpress. But i need the old URLs to continue working.

So the URL structure is now:
**example.com/category/postname**

And by adding a parent category, it will turn into: 
**example.com/new-parent-category/category/postname**

How can i make sure that the old URLs keep working?

I don´t want to write a custom redirect for every single post.

Could you maybe accomplish this with a regex redirect in htaccess?

Comment: Not sure but doesn't WordPress handle this redirection automatically? Have you tried already?

Comment: I haven´t tried, but you way be right! I can´t find any documentation about how that works. I will set up a test environment to check. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

In file .htaccess, You can try this way:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /new-parent-category/category/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

In this way all the links that contain the "category" will be redirected to "/new-parent-category/category/.."

You can visit this page to read more..

[Read more..](https://www.unsitoweb.it/come-impostare-redirect-301-tramite-file-htaccess.html)